# AR-HMM how to learn parameters

Tags: c++, python, scikit-learn

I am looking for a way either in python or C++ to learn the parameters of an AR-HMM model. 
There are many package to do fitting and inference for HMM when emission probabilities are only conditional on the hidden state but I cannot seem to find one when emission probabilities are conditional on both the state and prior observations.

Available :
[image: HMM]
<sub>(source: [tugraz.at](http://www.igi.tugraz.at/lehre/MLA/WS11/MLA_Exercises_2011/FG_HMM.png))</sub>

Cannot find:

[AR-HMM http://mayer.pro/files/HMM-web/HMM-ar.png](http://mayer.pro/files/HMM-web/HMM-ar.png)

Does anyone know of such a package, the goal is to fit a regime switching AR(p) model. If it's possible to do regime switching ARMA(p,q) it's even better. 
Python/Cpp preferred. Open source .

Comment: GHMM has Python wrappers.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken GHMM only solves the problem which I mentioned as widely available i.e. Emission probabilities are conditioned on state only, it cannot fit the second type of model.